# jQuery ajax call with multiple dropdowns

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call like so:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/connection/getCommunities",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var communityDropdown = $("#communtiyDropdown");
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                communityDropdown.append($("<option />").val(key).text(key));
            });


        }
    });
```

This takes the data and puts the key into the dropdown menu. My data looks like the image attached (this a screenshot of my console log in chrome)

[image]

Now this same dropdown that I populated with using the ajax call, I created an on change event for it outside the ajax call.

```
$("#communtiyDropdown").on('change', function () {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
```

Now what I am looking to do is what ever key the user selects (example A2T) I want to populate another dropdown with the keys values....I hope this makes sense.

What I have tried so far is the following.

Created this array before my ajax call,

```
var items = [];
```

Then push the items into this array inside the ajax call inside the each

```
items.push({key: value});
```

My problem I am having is the key shows up as key, not the key variable just the word key, the values are populating like they should, but how do I get key variable for an object which is being pushed into the array ?

UPDATE

solved this by changing items.push({key: value}); to items[key] = value;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved this by changing `items.push({key: value});` to `items[key] = value;`

Comment: did you solve it yourself or cuz of Rory answer? if cuz of rory plz accept his answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the value of a variable as the property name of an object, you need to use bracket notation. Try this:

```
var obj = {};
obj[key] = value;
items.push(obj);
```